# Can I make Prompto stop using certain filters in his pictures?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I have had many great photo ops ruined by overexposure or lack of color. I know I unlocked these filters, but is there a way to disable them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's actually a way to disable filters or even make them more common.

The menu is found by going to `Archives`->`Photos`->`Filters`

From there, you can set each filter to be used Randomly, Often, Sometimes, or Never.

[image: filter settings menu]

Credit to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5gufsa/psa_you_can_choose_which_kinds_of_filters_promoto/) for discovering it.